# Zeros of L function on imaginary axis

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Could someone please tell me what results are known about the zeros of L function, $L(s,\chi)$ on the imaginary axis, where $\chi$ is a character mod $q$?
In particular, what is known about zeta function?
I guess there are none because we know $L(1+it)$ is non zero from the euler product and the functional equation gives $L(it)\neq 0$. Not sure if I am missing something.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this turns out to be a fully solved problem. If $\chi$ is a *primitive* character modulo $q$, then $L(s,\chi)$ has no zeros on the imaginary axis except for a trivial zero at $s=0$ when $\chi$ is an even character. This follows from the functional equation and the fact that $L(1+it,\chi)\ne0$.

If $\chi$ is *imprimitive*, though, we usually get arithmetic progressions of zeros on the imaginary axis. Suppose that the primitive character $\chi^*$ (mod $q^*$) induces the character $\chi$ (mod $q$). Then we have
$$
L(s,\chi) = L(s,\chi^*) \prod_{\substack{p\mid q \\ p\nmid q^*}} \biggl( 1 - \frac{\chi^*(p)}{p^s} \biggr).
$$
For each prime $p$ dividing $q$ but not $q^*$, this results in zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ of the form $s = it$ for $t = (\arg\chi^*(p)+2\pi n)/\log p$ for all integers $n$.